# How to change reCAPTCHA language on websites?

Tags: language, captcha

I want reCAPTCHA to be shown in English on all websites i visit like sign up pages and etc, but it is in Persian. Like this:

[image]

I tried Changing language in account settings to refresh it, clearing cookies, history, etc. Nothing worked.
How can I change the language reCAPTCHA uses for me to English?

**UPDATE**
I tested on IE and Edge browser and reCAPTCHA is English in those browsers. just in chrome it is still Persian. any suggestion to make it English on Chrome?

Comment: FYI, Google is releasing a new reCAPTCHA which will be completely invisible: https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/03/googles-recaptcha-announces-invisible-background-captchas/  https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/invisible.html But to answer your question, it looks like you can force it to render in a specific language: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#config

Comment: @wysiwyg I'm pretty sure it is not forced to Persian.because:  
1. Site is in USA and is in English language  
2. I live in Iran, but my account language settings are English.  
Please let me know if i have missed anything in settings, or any help

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I thought you were talking about a specific reCAPTCHA that you are putting on your website. But you mean all reCAPTCHAs on all websites display to you in Farsi? And you're sure your google language is set to English? https://myaccount.google.com/intro/preferences

Comment: @wysiwyg That's right. both my "Language" and "Input Tools" are on English, and it is only language i specified for my account but still all reCAPTCHAs in all websites are Persian/Farsi. i tested here at [Demo reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo) and also this page is shown in persian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked languages in chrome settings and there was Persian language beside English. After removing Persian everything is fine now and reCAPTCHAs are in English.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what is your version reCAPTCHA.

**In version 2**, you just need to specify the parameter `?hl=` in the script's URL:

```html
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=fr'></script>
```

**In version 3**, you just need to specify the parameter `?lang=` in the script's URL:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=reCAPTCHA_site_key&lang=en
```

Comment: From the comments on the original question I conclude that default behavior without this parameter is to present the user's  preferred language in accordance with the browser setting. So for sites that do not set this URL parameter the work around is to change  browser's language preferences.

Comment: In Version 3 , For Persian Language  ?hl=fa Works

Answer (score 1):

Change language in reCaptcha url explicitly,

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?explicit&hl=fa'> for Persian
or 
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?explicit&hl=en'> for English
or any other language